# How to correctly compose a game "Buy / Sell Item" transaction

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a "Buy/Sell Item" functionality for an rpg game. If I am correct following actions need to happen in a single transaction

1. Get player based on `playerID` from "Players" table
2. Check if player has enough gold, if so create new item object
3. Write new item object to "Items" table, where owner is based on `pllayerID`
4. Update "Players" table row where owner is `playerID`, deduct gold based on item cost

If in above players gold changes while transaction is running or step `3` or `4` fail to execute simultaneously transaction should fail.

I've read the docs and can see that DynamoDB has `TransactWriteItems` and `TransactGetItems` which seem to be perfect for this, but are separate. Can I somehow use them in a single transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your `playerID`, you should be able to merge step 4 into step 2 and then do steps 2-3 within one `TransactWriteItems`:

2. `UPDATE` the value of the gold conditionally - if enough gold is present, deduct the item cost immediately, else condition fails, and so does `TransactWriteItems`.
3. If you made it here, there was enough gold, and you can create and write the new object to the `Items` table.

Edit for explanation as to why this works:

`TransactWriteItems` groups the actions "Update gold" and "put item" as a single
all-or-nothing operation: either they both succeed or they both fail. And if another operation interferes, they also both fail (no race condition).

For example:

- If there is not enough gold, the update fails, so the add item also fails.
- If adding the item fails, the changes made to the gold will not be kept (the update will "fail")
- If another operation is modifying the gold amount, both fail.

Essentially, it is impossible to either:

1. subtract the gold, but not add the item
2. add the item but not subtract the gold

Because they are both within the `TransactWriteItems` operation, either both happen, or neither does.

You can find an example in Java [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-example.html). (For your use case, you can simply drop the customer validation and change "product status update" to "player gold update" and "add order" to "add item".)

For more details, see `TransactWriteItems` documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html).

Comment: This still sounds like separate steps where values can change in race conditions, I might be misunderstanding though. Any chance you could provide an example (any code language will do)

Comment: I edited the answer with an explanation about TransactWriteItems atomicity and link to example. Hope this helps, let me know if something is still not clear.